# Django | Error when insert imageName with for into static url

Tags: django

Error when we want to insert image file name into static url. No all has imageName.

Error:

Invalid block tag

Code:

```
<img width="40%" src="{% static 'files/img/
{% for i in questions %}
  {% i.imageName %}
{% endfor %}
' %}">
```

Comment: This does not make much sense, a `static` template tag can accept only one parameter, here you iterate over the questions, so it can contain several items (if that would work, because it is invalid syntax as well).

Comment: Only has one question per page, because i use Paginator with only one question per page.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't built into Django but you can try something along these lines.

```
files = os.listdir(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, "files/img"))

{% for file in files %}
    <img width="40%" src="{{file}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
{% for i in questions %}
<img width="40%" src="{% static 'files/img/{{i.imageName}}' %}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: In cases like this, where a previous answer has a minor syntax error, it’s more appropriate to comment on that answer—or, better yet, just suggest an edit to it—rather than repost their answer with the minor corrections. (Though, in this case, I’m not even sure if it’s a syntax error?)

Comment: my answer has nothing to do with the other answer I just posted it independently from the other answer and I posted it before the other answer was posted!

Answer (score -1):

try

```
{% for i in questions %}
<img width="40%" src="{% static "files/img/{{i.imageName.url }}" %}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why would you need static if you're asking the path to an uploaded file in the MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.